# Summary of outputs from for loop so it outputs a summary

Tags: c#, console-application

Trying to get a summary from my current output. E.g. Hello: 5, World: 8, HelloWorld: 20, integer: 5. Currently this accepts a user input e.g. 1,10, 1 being minimum and 10 being maximum and outputs the following from the for loop. Don't know how to get the output into an array and then aggregate this.

Code so far:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Please enter a range?");
        string range = Console.ReadLine();
        string first = range.Split(',')[0];
        string last = range.Split(',')[1];
        int min = Int32.Parse(first);
        int max = Int32.Parse(last);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Heres the Output");
        Console.WriteLine("");

        for (int i = min; i < max ; i++ )
        {
            bool hello = i % 3 == 0;
            bool world = i % 5 == 0;

            if (hello && world)
                Console.WriteLine("HelloWorld");

            else if (hello)
                Console.WriteLine("Hello");
            else if (world)
                Console.WriteLine("World");
            else
                Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

        string list = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(list);
```

Comment: Could you, please, provide *some examples*? E.g. what is the desired `array` on, say `[min = 8, max = 14]` input?

Comment: User input: 1,10

Current output:
1
2
hello
4
world
hello
7
8
hello

Comment: I want to do:
hello: 3
world: 1
integer: 5

Comment: provided an example above with input 1,10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to use modular arithmetics; providing that `0 <= min < max` :

```
private static int CountDivs(int value, int divisor) {
  return value < 0 ? 0 : value / divisor + 1;
}

private static string Solution(int min, int max) {
  int hello = CountDivs(max - 1, 3) - CountDivs(min - 1, 3);
  int world = CountDivs(max - 1, 5) - CountDivs(min - 1, 5);
  int helloWorld = CountDivs(max - 1, 3 * 5) - CountDivs(min - 1, 3 * 5);
  // others: Inclusion–exclusion principle  
  int other = max - min - hello - world + helloWorld;

  return $"hello: {hello} world: {world} integer: {other}"; 
}

// Test (your example)
Console.WriteLine(Solution(1, 10));
// My comment [8..14) i.e. 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13
Console.WriteLine(Solution(8, 14));
```

Outcome:

```
hello: 3 world: 1 integer: 5
hello: 2 world: 1 integer: 3
```

Please, notice, that the solution has `O(1)` time complexity (loop will be *inefficient*, on inputs like `Solution(100, 1000000000)`)

**Edit:** if you want to *change* your *current code* a bit and have an aggregate solution, you can try to *extract* the loop into a *method* and use *Linq* to aggregate the items:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static IEnumerable<string> Generator(int min, int max) {
  // Your loop extracted: put "yield return ..." instead of "Console.WriteLine(...)"
  for (int i = min; i < max; ++i) {
    bool hello = i % 3 == 0;
    bool world = i % 5 == 0;

    if (hello && world) {
      // Or if you want return twice, just do it twice:
      // yield return "Hello";
      // yield return "World";

      yield return "HelloWorld";
    } 
    else if (hello)
      yield return "Hello";
    else if (world)
      yield return "World";
    else
      yield return "integer";
  }
}

...

var data = Generator(1, 10)
  .GroupBy(item => item)
  .OrderBy(chunk => chunk.Key)
  .Select(chunk => $"{chunk.Key}: {chunk.Count()}");

var result = string.Join(" ", data);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Outcome:

```
Hello: 3 integer: 5 World: 1
```

**Edit 2**: No *Linq* solution, manual grouping

```
int min = 1;
int max = 10;

Dictionary<string, int> counts = new Dictionary<string, int>() {
  { "HelloWorld", 0},
  { "Hello", 0},
  { "World", 0},
  { "integer", 0},
};

foreach (var item in Generator(1, 10))
  counts[item] += 1;

string result = 
  $"Hello: {counts["Hello"]} World: {counts["World"]} integer: {counts["integer"]}";

Console.Write(result);
```

Outcome:

```
Hello: 3 World: 1 integer: 5
```

Comment: Thanks. Just so I understand is this the only way to do it? My idea was to somehow output the for loop into an array then loop through the array and aggregate on that.

Comment: I don't understand modular arithmetic's, might need to read up on this.

Comment: @RA19: loop can appear a bad choice when range is *wide*, e.g. `100..1000000000`

Comment: Is it possible to show me how we would do it that way though? Lets say if the range would always be small. E.g. 5,10 or 10, 20 or 10-15.

Comment: @RA19: I've edited the answer (loop solution provided). Typical solution is to implement a `IEnumerable<T>` - `IEnumerable<string>` in your case and use *Linq* to aggregate the data

Comment: Thanks very much! Il have a look at this. Just to confirm. What is Linq?

Comment: @RA19: Linq (*Linq to Objects* in the code) is queries over `IEnumerable<T>` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-objects

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159169/discussion-between-ra19-and-dmitry-bychenko).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159173/discussion-between-ra19-and-dmitry-bychenko).